# How to periodically relogin with selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

The site i'am scraping shows an exception every almost 20 minutes 'the session is expired because of inactivity '
Is there a way to fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to click on some element on the page or perform some action with `Actions` class, like hovering over some sensitive element or even refresh the page.

Comment: thank you am working on it now , i hope it works

Comment: It should. You have to simulate user's activity on the web page.

Comment: @Ranya Hfayedh Please accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of refreshing a page in Selenium, I think the most used way of refreshing a webpage is with this command.

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Comment: thank you i hope it works , because i already iterate the url with adding new parameters while scrapping , but i guess its not the same  as refreshing the same  url